# bar chart with multiple bars and 1 label

Tags: chart.js

[Sample grouped stacked bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbdCx.jpg)

Above is a sample chart.  The colored parts of the bars are tickets opened.  The diamond part of the bars are tickets closed.  I only want 1 label for tickets closed.

```
var ctxMonthly = document.getElementById('monthlyTkts').getContext('2d');
            var chartMonthly = new Chart(ctxMonthly, {
                // The type of chart we want to create
                type: "bar",
                    // The data for our dataset
                data: {
                    labels: ["Week 1", "Week 2", "Week 3", "Week 4"],
                    datasets: [
                    {
//                      label: "Critical-Opened",
                        stack: "Critical",
                        backgroundColor: ["red", "red", "red", "red"],
                        borderColor: ["black", "black", "black", "black"],
                        data: 
                            <?php echo json_encode($monthlyOpenedData[0]); ?>
                    },
                    {
//                      label: "Critical-Closed",
                        stack: "Critical",
                        backgroundColor: ["purple", "purple", "purple", "purple"],
                        borderColor: ["black", "black", "black", "black"],
                        data: 
                            <?php echo json_encode($monthlyClosedData[0]); ?>
                    },
                    {
//                      label: "Urgent-Opened",
                        stack: "Urgent",
                        backgroundColor: ["orange", "orange", "orange", "orange"],
                        borderColor: ["black", "black", "black", "black"],
                        data: 
                            <?php echo json_encode($monthlyOpenedData[1]); ?>
                    },
                    {
//                      label: "Urgent-Closed",
                        stack: "Urgent",
                        backgroundColor: ["purple", "purple", "purple", "purple"],
                        borderColor: ["black", "black", "black", "black"],
                        data: 
                            <?php echo json_encode($monthlyClosedData[1]); ?>
                    },
                    {
//                      label: "Elevated-Opened",
                        stack: "Elevated",
                        backgroundColor: ["green", "green", "green", "green"],
                        borderColor: ["black", "black", "black", "black"],
                        data: 
                            <?php echo json_encode($monthlyOpenedData[2]); ?>
                    },
                    {
//                      label: "Elevated-Closed",
                        stack: "Elevated",
                        backgroundColor: ["purple", "purple", "purple", "purple"],
                        borderColor: ["black", "black", "black", "black"],
                        data: 
                            <?php echo json_encode($monthlyClosedData[2]); ?>
                    },
                    {
//                      label: "General-Opened",
                        stack: "General",
                        backgroundColor: ["blue", "blue", "blue", "blue"],
                        borderColor: ["black", "black", "black", "black"],
                        data: 
                            <?php echo json_encode($monthlyOpenedData[3]); ?>
                    },
                    {
//                      label: "General-Closed",
                        stack: "General",
                        backgroundColor: ["purple", "purple", "purple", "purple"],
                        borderColor: ["black", "black", "black", "black"],
                        data: 
                            <?php echo json_encode($monthlyClosedData[3]); ?>
                    }]
                },
                    // Configuration options go here
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    legendCallback: function(chartMonthly) {
                        var text = [];
                        text.push('<ul class="list-inline">');
                        var bgColorsMonthly = ["red", "orange", "green", "blue", "purple"];
                        var chartLabelsMonthly = ["Critical", "Urgent", "Elevated", "General", "Closed"];

                        for(var i = 0;i < 5; i++) {
                            text.push('<li class="list-inline-item btn text-white" style=" background: ' + bgColorsMonthly[i] + ' ">');
                            text.push(chartLabelsMonthly[i]);
                            text.push('</li>');
                        }

                        text.push('</ul>');
                        return text.join("");
                    },
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            stacked: true,
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            stacked: true,
                            ticks : {
                                min : 0
                            }
                        }]
                    },
                    legend: {
                        display: false,
                        labels: {
                            boxWidth: 15,
    //                      usePointStyle: true,
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            document.getElementById('monthlyLabels').innerHTML = chartMonthly.generateLegend();
```

OK, so I figured out that I needed to use generateLegend to achieve what I wanted with the labels.  Is there anyway for format the legend to look like the auto generated legend and still achieve what I want?

Comment: please provide some example data and show us what you did so far

Comment: so to make the chart I guess the data is coming in json format, can you provide some example of the array, and maybe a graphic example of how do you expect the chart to look?

Comment: Are you asking us how to make that entire chart (bad), or is there a specific problem with what you've done so far that you'd like help with (good)? In the latter case please edit your code into your question as detailed in [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I edited the post and added a sample output chart.  I can post the code if needed.

Comment: @oldgeek69 Will be better to see a snippet or a plunker or any other thing that shows the code you did to better see what the problem can be